# Is it possible to add sim card capability aka cellular connectivity and data (4G / LTE) to a laptop?

Tags: laptop, cellular-internet, sim, system-modification

I am aware that there exists small WiFi hotspot devices that you can plug a sim card to and you connect to it via WiFi using your devices. However, I'm looking to use a sim card on my laptop the same way I would on an Android tablet or an iPad so that the data is internal.

Is there a way for me to introduce this feature to a laptop that didn't come built in with it? Maybe a USB dongle or (even better) an internal component I can attach to the motherboard?

Comment: search for "USB LTE modem" or "MPCI LTE Module" ? you've not specified the laptop so no idea what ports are available.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Mini-PCI-Adapter-card-Module/dp/B01J705MTC

Comment: It's called an WWAN module

Comment: @DavidPostill I think this close vote was a bit overzealous.  The OP was looking for the appropriate term or type of device - I don't think he was looking for a particular product or recommedation.

Comment: What laptop?  A lot of laptops can take a WWAN card but don't come with them installed.   If your laptop supports it, google "LTE M.2", remembering that your device will need antennas for it as well.

Comment: @davidgo Is there a way to find out when I open the laptop up? Because I'm also replacing a few parts so I'll be opening it anyway. It's an early model IdeaPad